# Start native service at early-init before coldboot done

Tags: android, android-service, android-source

Boot sequence in Android is defined via `system/core/rootdir/init.rc` and other `*.rc` files. Such approach allows to bind any action to any boot stage (`early-init`, `init`, etc). Also in `system/core/init/init.cpp` is defined the following sequence of the boot:
 - `...`;
 - `early-init`;
 - `wait_for_coldboot_done`;
 - `...`;
 - `init`;
 - `...`.

It means that some action inside imported `*.rc` file binded to the `early-init` stage can be started before `coldboot` (and SELinux initialization) will be finished by the `ueventd`.

So my question: does a native service work correctly if it will be started before `coldboot` done (obviously it means that such service does not require any device which should be created by the `ueventd`)?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question: does a native service work correctly if it will be started before `coldboot` done?

Sometimes it may work correct but in general case it may fail. If native service doesn't interact with any device it doesn't require the `/dev/` file system. But binderized services communicate via [Binder IPC](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/) which is require opening the binder driver (for interact between kernel and userspace layers):

**frameworks/native/include/binder/BinderService.h**:

```
template<typename SERVICE>
class BinderService
{
public:
    ...
    static void instantiate() { publish(); }
    ...
    static status_t publish(bool allowIsolated = false) {
        sp<IServiceManager> sm(defaultServiceManager());
        return sm->addService(
                String16(SERVICE::getServiceName()),
                new SERVICE(), allowIsolated);
    }
```

**frameworks/native/libs/binder/IServiceManager.cpp**:

```
sp<IServiceManager> defaultServiceManager()
{
                ...
                ProcessState::self()->getContextObject(NULL));
```

**frameworks/native/libs/binder/ProcessState.cpp**:

```
sp<ProcessState> ProcessState::self()
{
    ...
    gProcess = new ProcessState("/dev/binder");
    return gProcess;
}

ProcessState::ProcessState(const char *driver)
    : mDriverName(String8(driver))
    , mDriverFD(open_driver(driver))
    ...
    {
        if (mDriverFD >= 0) {
        // mmap the binder, providing a chunk of virtual address space to receive transactions.
        mVMStart = mmap(0, BINDER_VM_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE, mDriverFD, 0);
        if (mVMStart == MAP_FAILED) {
            // *sigh*
            ...
            ALOGE("Using /dev/binder failed: unable to mmap transaction memory.\n");
    LOG_ALWAYS_FATAL_IF(mDriverFD < 0, "Binder driver could not be opened.  Terminating.");
}

static int open_driver(const char *driver)
{
    int fd = open(driver, O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (fd >= 0) {
    ...
    } else {
        ALOGW("Opening '%s' failed: %s\n", driver, strerror(errno));
    }
    return fd;
}
```

But the Binder driver `/der/binder` (as well as `/dev/hwbinder` and `/dev/vndbinder`) is created at the `coldboot` stage by the `ueventd` according to `ueventd.rc`.

**system/core/rootdir/ueventd.rc**:

```
...
/dev/binder               0666   root       root
/dev/hwbinder             0666   root       root
/dev/vndbinder            0666   root       root
...
```

So if a native service was be started before `coldboot` done it wouldn't open the `/dev/binder`!

Also at before `coldboot` done the `cgrops` and `SELinux` (not sure) are not initialized:
**system/core/rootdir/init.rc**:

```
on init
    ...
    # Mount cgroup mount point for cpu accounting
    mount cgroup none /acct cpuacct
    mkdir /acct/uid
```

P.S. But if a service communicates in [passthrough](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/#passthrough) mode?